# file uploading using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, zip, jszip

This is my code to generate a zip file; I am unable to upload a `.zip` file to server, displaying error like [[Promise]] is not a file:

```
    var zip = new JSZip();

    zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n");

  /*create a folder*/

    var img = zip.folder("images");

  /*create a file in images folder*/

    img.file("Hello1.txt", "Hello111 World\n");

  /* generate the zip file */

    var content = zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"});
```

This is the code I tried to upload the zip file but got no response.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fileZip', content);
$.ajax({
      data: fd,
      url: '/plan-upload/1',
      type: 'POST',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(response) {
        alert("success"); /*$('#text-us').modal('toggle');*/
      }
    });
```

Now, can we upload this generated zip file to server? If yes, how? If no, why?

Comment: What are you doing to upload the file to the server?

Comment: `Now, can we upload this generated zip file to server?` Did you actually tried?

Comment: `an we upload this generated zip file to server?` yes. `how?` - I recommend to start looking here: [**how to upload a zip file to a server using javascript**](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+upload+a+zip+file+to+a+server+using+javascript&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIE751IE751&oq=how+to+upload+a+zip+file+to+a+server+using+javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57.7793j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) then try to see if any of those solutions are something you can try out. If you have problems with a specific part in your code during that stage post it here and we check it out.

Comment: @Pavan, can you please update the question?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we generating the zip doing this code

> `var content = zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"});`

In **content** variable has some object type date like [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [Blob type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). 
So backend code doesn't recognize it as a file,Now do this

```
var file = new File([content], "name.zip");
```

Now we can send this **file**, doing this

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fileZip', file);
$.ajax({
  data: fd,
  url: '/plan-upload/1',
  type: 'POST',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(response) {
    alert("success"); /*$('#text-us').modal('toggle');*/
  }
});
```